# Java TarInputStream read file names of a tar.gz file which included another tar.gz file

Tags: java, gzip, tar, gzipinputstream

I'm trying to get file names of a tar.gz file inside another tar.gz file. Here is the sample code;

```
try (TarInputStream tis = getStreamRemoteTarGz(url)) { // accessing the first tar.gz file
    TarEntry e;
    while ((e = tis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
        if (e.getName().endsWith(".tar.gz")) {
             // accessing the inner tar.gz file (java.io.FileNotFoundException: inner_tar_file.tar.gz (No such file or directory))
             try (TarInputStream innerTis = new TarInputStream(new GZIPInputStream(new FileInputStream(entry.getName())))) {
                ....
        }
    }
```

As a result, I got FileNotFoundException: inner_tar_file.tar.gz. The file name (inner_tar_file.tar.gz) is correct, I can access the name of inner tar.gz file, but I want to access file names that included in this tar.gz file. How can I access file names of inner tar.gz file using TarInputStream?

Comment: Could be that nesting is unsupported. Not sure, but have memories of that being the case

Comment: I can do inner operatins after defining TarInputStream. Nesting is supported because the first try-catch block works properly but I couldn't read the contents of inner tar.gz file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of a tar file is not in itself a file. At least not in the sense of `java.io.File`, which represents a *real physical file* directly on a file system).

`java.io.File` represents anything that can be adressed with a path like `C:\somePath\myFile.ext` (on Windows) or `/home/user/somepath/myFile.ext` (on most other OS). There's no such path that points directly to *an entry inside a `.tar.gz`* that the operating system would understand.

Instead of creating a new `FileInputStream` simply pass in the `TarInputStream` named `tis`.

Comment: Hehe. Silly me for not scrolling the window to see that `FileInputStream`

Comment: It works thanks, but this time I got "java.io.IOException: reading from an output buffer" for the first while loop ".... e = tis.getNextEntry()) != null) { ...."

Comment: I suspect that's because the try-with-resources will close everything, including the `tis`. It's weird, but I think in this case you *should not* close the streams. `TarInputStream` is weird as it represents *both* the whole TAR stream *and* the `InputStream` for individual entries. So if you close it, you'll close the whole TAR stream.